# Prisma error message: Do you want to continue? All data will be lost. » (y/N)

Tags: node.js, react-native, graphql, prisma

I've faced the error message like  `Do you want to continue? All data will be lost. » (y/N)` from prisma.
So I type 'y' and then all data of prisma was gone.
Can I revert it back? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, unless you manually created some backup beforehand.

I suggest you to create some seeding script so you could consistently re-create the database state, it's very useful for your development environment.

[More info](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database)

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I shouldn't have clicked 'yes' T_T btw but my expo app keeps showing the previous data that was seen on prisma studio but not now. what are they different? can you help me more?

Comment: detailed my questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749670/why-isnt-my-prisma-server-data-reflected-correctly-to-expo